# Creating relationship links in PostgreSQL via pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I created a databse with four tables in pgAdmin. It was coded in PostgreSQL.

I was wondering how do you create replationship links in pgAdmin? I've searched google and youtube, but can't seem to find a tutorial on it.

If someone can explain how to do this, i'll be grateful.

Here's a picture of how I designed my datase to relate:

[image: relationship design]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find it via right-click on the table `--> Properties --> Constraints --> Foreign Key (Add)`.

Then you can add the foreign keys as needed. There is (yet) no way to do it graphically.

Comment: I would highly recommend to not use a wizard for things like that. The `ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT .. ` should be stored in a SQL script that in turn is stored in the version control system.

Comment: Absolutely, but since the question was about how to do it in pgAdmin, I didn't took best practices into account.

Comment: @DrColossos, Thanks mate. I just managed to work it out. I did it manually by the way.

Comment: just curious why you all think its so taboo to use the wizard for something like this? i've ran into weird issues with the wizard for things like changing column types but when it works it works no issues...these comments are old so maybe its not an issue any more but again just curious...